# IllegalArgumentException in StatFs in WebViewCore internal thread

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

Google play reports an exception on some devices (all are "other" and one "LG-E400", so it might be some custom android build)

Exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.os.StatFs.native_setup(Native Method)
at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:32)
at android.webkit.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:199)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.<init>(BrowserFrame.java:210)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.initialize(WebViewCore.java:201)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$500(WebViewCore.java:54)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:653)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

The problem is I can't ignore this axception 'cause it is in separate thread.
Is there any solution for this problem?
 Or what can I do with that?

Comment: Definitely seems like an OS issue. For us it happens exclusively on LG Optimus L3 and LG-E405 so you could black list those for now. They are essentially the same device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much likely it's a device OS bug. I have much problems with AudioRecord library - it also fails in native init on number of devices like Yusu, Micromax, Alcatel and other low range devices. They are all shown as "other" in GooglePlay reports. Also I encoundered that some [Cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) ROMs have a bug in AudioRecord - on my HTC One V it worked okay until I flashed CM10.
One good way to know exact device model, logcats, mem and other info about what happens on these devices is to use some advanced crash report tool, as [ACRA](http://acra.ch/)
After I get report that something is definitely wrong on device with it's manufacturer's firmware, I blacklist it on GooglePlay.

Answer (score 2):

Path which you are providing in Statfs constructor does not exists

```
  String path = "path to some directory";
StatFs statFs = null;
statFs = new StatFs(path);
```

and you must have external storage permission in manifest file

Comment: If `File path` points to a non-existing file in a existing directory, use `path.getParent()` to pass the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some firmware had problem with StatFs

I had similar issue with  Samsung Galaxy Stratosphere™ II (Verizon) SCH-I415, Android:4.1.2
When I call:

```
 StatFs statFs = null;
 statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```

I got exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at android.os.StatFs.native_setup(Native Method)
 at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:32)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got similar issue and my log was looking like

```
03-14 13:41:55.715: E/PayPalService(14037): Risk component failed to initialize, threw null
03-14 13:41:56.295: E/(14037): statfs /storage/sdcard0 failed, errno: 13
03-14 13:41:56.365: E/AndroidRuntime(14037): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1219
03-14 13:41:56.365: E/AndroidRuntime(14037): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
03-14 13:41:56.365: E/AndroidRuntime(14037): at android.os.StatFs.native_setup(Native Method)
03-14 13:41:56.365: E/AndroidRuntime(14037): at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:32)
```

I found this issue related to sd card by looking the first two lines .Then I checked device setting and found I had checked their a option **apps must have permission to read sd card** and the app I was installing was not having **READ SD CARD** permission in manifest. So possibly these things are related and possible solutions for me were either put permission in manifest or to unchecke that option .Hope it will help in further research.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Lollipop, Android placed rather extreme restrictions on accessing external SD cards.  You can use:

```
    StatFs stat;
    try {
        stat = new StatFs(path);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // Handle the failure gracefully or just throw(e)
    }
```

to work-around the error.

For my application, I just skip unavailable directories, essentially limiting the user to the internal storage.  Not an ideal solution, but a limited application that doesn't crash is better than one which does.

Comment: nope.It's not about calling new StatFs() from my code. It's about new StatFs() called from android code. It is called in separate thead in WebView. I can't add try block there.